# Memory leakage Error

Tags: iphone

I have initialized an object like this

```
PixelInfo *ob=[[PixelInfo alloc]initWithName:clr :t];
```

within a for loop and release it within that for loop itself like this.

```
[faceColor addObject:ob];
[ob release];
```

But after iterating nearly 120 times i am gtting an error like this:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x5030400: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Could you post rest of the code in for loop? seems you are doing something with ob after you release?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post more of your code, for example what type of object is faceColor? Is the error occurring during the iteration or after iterating when using the data?

Comment: My suggestion is to enable the NSZombieEnabled environment variable: it will give you more information about what is the object that causes the problem. More info [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).

Comment: What is our motivation to answer if you cannot accept answers and give credit?